# Is it possible to run jenkins with two different iOS sdks

Tags: xcode, jenkins

We are using Jenkins to run our xcodebuilds on a Mac Mini server. In the last weeks we started development of iOS 7 apps and we installed Xcode 5 DP versions on the Mac Mini.

When installing a new Xcode version and configuring the xcodebuild of the new Xcode which xcode-select this new version is also used for building our old iOS 6 apps - which breaks the UI of them.

Is there a way to tell Jenkins which xcodebuild it should use to build a project?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check out the solution posted by Andy Molloy at http://andymolloy.net/specifying-xcode-version-for-jenkins-projects.

You have to install EnvInject plugin for Jenkins and add DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer environment variable to your build job.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it is possible to specify xcode version per jenkins job. Also switching xcode version on the command line requires root permissions.

You might manage to solve your issue by making sure your IOS 6 apps, when built with the new xcode, work properly. Try selecting the proper base SDK and deployment target http://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/06/23/sdks-and-deployment-targets/

If that won't work you could try forcing a switch of the xcode version to use at build time, pre xcode plugin use. You will have to fiddle with sudo rights. Given that this is a system setting, you might need to prevent multiple builds from happening simultaneously.

I would do my best getting the multiple builds working with a single xcode version though.

Comment: It's possible to switch xcode version in Jenkins. Before we run that command, run this in a terminal first. 

    $sudo xcodebuild –license

Answer (score 0):

Select the xcode version at runtime

1. Use EnvInject plugin
2. for jobs that require the non default do something like

DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode6.0.1.app/Contents/Developer

under Inject environment variables to the build process

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin